# Sharing an app URL using Facebook SDK redirecting wrong

Tags: javascript, facebook, fb.ui

I have a "share" button in my application that isn't working as it might.

I'm following these steps:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

And the URL I want to share is:

https://www.facebook.com/RestauranteViena/app_216009158592464

So, I ended up with this code:

```
$('#share_button').click(function(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://www.facebook.com/RestauranteViena/app_216009158592464',
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the URL Facebook is sharing is not the App URL but the PAGE URL.

The URL it redirects me is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/RestauranteViena?fb_action_ids=711183428925062&fb_action_types=og.shares&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582
```

Have anyone walked through this?

Comment: Already tried removing that comma after the href.